# WHERE id=(array)

Tags: php, sql

The code below only outputs single line(there are 2 in database that should be outputed).

I think that problem is in *id=$data[id]* since data1 is array instead of single value.I hoped that *while* will fix that but it doesnt look too good...

```
    $results1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM keywords WHERE keyword='$search' ORDER BY (relevant-irrelevant) DESC");
    $data1=mysql_fetch_array($results1);
    $results2=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM searchengine WHERE id='$data1[id]'");
    while($data2=mysql_fetch_array($results2))
```

Comment: be careful... you might have with sql injection...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, isolate your ids, looping to get all of the results:

```
$ids = array();

while ( $data1 = mysql_fetch_array($results1) ) {
    $ids[] = $data1['id'];
}
```

Then, convert your $ids array into a string. An easy way to do this is via [implode()](http://php.net/implode):

```
$results2=mysql_query(
    "SELECT * FROM searchengine WHERE id IN (" . implode(',', $ids) . ")"
    );
```

Comment: `$data1` is an array, `$data1[id]` is a single value; the value of field `id` in the `keywords` table.

Comment: @jeroen: Good catch. I didn't understand that from the initial post. Answer has been updated.

Comment: It fixed my initial problem but convertion to string lefts out the ORDER BY 
(ORDER BY keywords.relevant DESC)at the end of 2nd query doesnt work,any ideas how to add order by from 1st query.NOTE: selectiong both databases on beggining of 2nd query (searchengine, keywords) selects copies.

Comment: You will need to order the results by a column in the searchengine table, rather than one in the keywords table. Which column in searchengine do you wish to order by?

Comment: I did that by script that copies the values from keyvordsDB to searchengineDB when they are changed,I was just wandering if there is better way to sort this without moving data around.

Comment: If you don't provide an explicit ORDER BY, the database will return the data in whatever order it chooses, regardless of the order of your WHERE arguments. The only way to control the order is to add an ORDER BY clause.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe I´m missing something, but how can `$data1['id']` be an array? it´s probably an integer and perhaps a string, but it's not an array. `$data1['id']` is a single value; the value of field `id` in the `keywords` table

I think you just need to put curly quotes around the variable:

```
$results2=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM searchengine WHERE id='{$data1[id]}'");
```

or even better:

```
$results2=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM searchengine WHERE id=" . (int) $data1['id']);
```

If `id` is an integer that is.

And of course if the first query returns more than 1 result, you will have to loop through them as well.

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't you just select the entire thing in one query?

```
SELECT *
FROM keywords k
     searchengine s
WHERE k.keyword='$search'
AND k.id = s.id
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    $results1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM keywords WHERE keyword='$search' ORDER BY (relevant-irrelevant) DESC");
    $data1=mysql_fetch_array($results1);
//VERY DANGEROUS TO USE USER INPUT
$in = join(',',$data1['id']);
    $results2=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM searchengine WHERE id IN ({$in})");
    while($data2=mysql_fetch_array($results2))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't pass array as condition. You should:

a. do a for(each) loop in the $data1 array and perform next actions

b. implode the array and search with `IN`. Example:

`$commaSeparated = implode(",", $data1);`

`$results2=mysql_query('SELECT * FROM searchengine WHERE id IN ('.$commaSeparated.'));`

Answer (score 0):

mads.ohm is correct about combining the two queries into a single query.

As for your problem with only getting one return value, your while loop is just overwriting the contents of $data2 each time through.

You could write something like this instead:

```
$i = 0;
$data2 = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($results2)) {

    $data2[$i] = $row;
    $i++;

}
```

In this case, $data2 is declared as an array, and each iteration of the while loop adds a row from the database to the array.